# Zelle Python Chapter 4 Q1: Why can't I use clone()?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

The question is to modify the program below so that each successive click will draw an additional square on the screen.

Here is the program to be modified.

```
   def main():
win = GraphWin()
shape = Rectangle(Point(50,50), Point(70,70))
shape.setOutline("red")
shape.setFill("red")
shape.draw(win)
for i in range(10):
    p = win.getMouse()
    c = shape.getCenter()
    dx = p.getX() - c.getX()
    dy = p.getY() - c.getY()
    shape.move(dx,dy)
win.close()
```

To solve this, I have employed the clone() function. Here is my solution:

```
 def main():
win = GraphWin()
shape = Rectangle(Point(50,50), Point(70,70))
shape.setOutline("red")
shape.setFill("red")
shape.draw(win)
for i in range(10):
    p = win.getMouse()
    c = shape.getCenter()
    dx = p.getX() - c.getX()
    dy = p.getY() - c.getY()
    pshaw = shape.clone()
    pshaw.move(dx, dy)
win.close()
```

However, the program does not work. Other solutions I have seen involve creating a new shape altogether as show below: Why can I not use clone()?

```
    def main():
win = GraphWin()
shape = Rectangle(Point(75,75),Point(125,125))
shape.setOutline('Red')
shape.setFill('Red')
shape.draw(win)

for i in range(5):
    p = win.getMouse()
    tx = p.getX()-25
    ty = p.getY()-25
    bx = p.getX()+25
    by = p.getY()+25

    shape2 = Rectangle(Point(tx,ty),Point(bx,by))
    shape2.setOutline('Red')
    shape2.setFill('Red')
    shape2.draw(win)


ct = Text(Point(100,180),'Click again to quit!')
ct.setStyle('bold')
ct.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

main()

Why does clone() not work here? Is this not the purpose it was created for? The proposed solution with its creating of a new shape from scratch seems redundant to me.

Any attempts to help are greatly appreciated and I would like to say thank you in advance :) My head is spinning- look forward to learning from the masters!

Answer (score 0):

Your simple clone-based solution works fine, you just left off the `pshaw.draw(win)` command to add your new rectangle to the window:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin()

shape = Rectangle(Point(50, 50), Point(70, 70))
shape.setOutline("red")
shape.setFill("red")
shape.draw(win)

for _ in range(10):
    p = win.getMouse()
    c = shape.getCenter()
    dx = p.getX() - c.getX()
    dy = p.getY() - c.getY()
    pshaw = shape.clone()
    pshaw.move(dx, dy)
    pshaw.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

[image]